# Another scraper: http://askproblem.com/

Tags: discussion, scraping

I was searching google for a solution to my problem - and found a stackoverflow question about it - [Application Cache Error event: Manifest fetch failed (4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27442031/application-cache-error-event-manifest-fetch-failed-4).  Answers in that question didn't help me - so I started looking at other google matches - and stumbled upon this one - http://askproblem.com/question/application-cache-error-event-manifest-fetch-failed-4/

As you can see, the content is the exact scrape of the stackoverflow question, even links to users, etc. - but there is no attribution and no even small print about about where the question came from.

Tsk-tsk... Bad doggy!